# Template with svg style url(#id) is shimmed with file name

Tags: svg, polymer, web-component

Consider this main document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bug</title>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="svg-bug.html">

</head>
<body>
<p>Directly:</p>
<svg width="50" height="20">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" orient="auto">
      <path d="M2,1 L2,10 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:red;" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <path d="M10,10 L40,10"
        style="stroke:#000000; stroke-width: 1.25px;
            fill:none;
            marker-end: url(#arrow);" ></path>
</svg>
<p>Imported:</p>
<svg-bug></svg-bug>
</body>
</html>
```

And `svg-bug.html` containing this:

```
<polymer-element name="svg-bug" noscript>
  <template>
    <svg width="50" height="20">
      <defs>
        <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" orient="auto">
          <path d="M2,1 L2,10 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:red;" />
        </marker>
      </defs>
      <path d="M10,10 L40,10"
            style="stroke:#000000; stroke-width: 1.25px;
            fill:none;
            marker-end: url(#arrow);" ></path>
    </svg>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Using Chromium Version 37.0.2062.94 Ubuntu 14.04 (290621) (64-bit) and Polymer 0.4.0. The result is this:

[image: Missing arrow head]

This is because the path's style attribut now contains `marker-end: url('svg-bug.html#arrow');`.

I tried using `no-shim` in various places with no luck.

How can I fix or work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug in Polymer, file an issue ticket here https://github.com/polymer/polymer/issues

Comment: Thanks, I will, and I'll update here when it's resolved! Edit: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/751

Comment: Seems this is fixed in 0.5.4, the [release notes](https://blog.polymer-project.org/releases/2015/01/28/release-0.5.4/#fixed-polymer-core-library-hash-urls-no-longer-rewritten) mention hash urls, but I won't bother digging up the specific ticket.